# Chrome/ Opera continue to save & autofill passwords after installing LastPass? Good or bad? Enable/ Disable?

Tags: web-browser, password-management, browser-extensions, lastpass

I started to use LastPass a few months ago and imported passwords from my browsers.

Apparently, Google Chrome and Opera (based on Chromium) still pop-up the option to store passwords in my browser and probably simultaneously trying to fill in forms automatically.

Recently a conflict occurred on a site while logging in. I think passwords were changed and there was a different password stored in the browser then in LastPass. The auto-fill was not working correctly and maybe both tried to auto-fill the form.

I guess it might make sense to disable browser password storage and browser auto-fill to avoid this conflict. I'd like to be sure about:

1. What is exactly happening?
2. What are the pros & cons of having both?
3. What is recommended to do?

Comment: Clear your browsers, deactivate saving passwords option on them,  delete related profiles to the websites that cause you trouble  and then create new ones on LastPass.

Answer (score 3):

**What's happening**

Both the built-in and Lastpass password managers are trying to auto fill/auto login and probably the built-in password manager gets precedence over Lastpass.

**Pros and cons**

Pros:
Your passwords are stored redundantly.

Cons:
Multiple popups to save /override passwords/login when saving new login data.

More efforts in terms of manageability.

**Recommendations**

- Turn off built-in password manager/lastpass (either via browser settings or use the option from Lastpass's settings.

Lastpass allows saving the cross browser& cross platform login info in cloud, so you can access it from any* device using your credentials. I suggest you use it.

*some device features are available only in premium and enterprise versions. Eg: mobile addons.

Comment: Kind of what I was thinking as well.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want to allow this to continue. However small the risk may be, there is some non-zero risk of every stored copy of your passwords being exposed. So there's just no reason to be in the situation that a successful attack on LastPass **or** Chrome stored passwords will expose your passwords.

BTW, if you've not set a [Chrome sync passphrase](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1181035?hl=en), then your passwords synced to Chrome can be read by Google. I'm not saying that they do read them or even that they store them in clear-text. Just that they have all the keys for decryption.

Comment: What are you talking about? I have a Sync Phrase set up. That is not my concern. My concern is parallel use of both versus using only one, say LastPass.